# Very slow tf.TensorArray and a possible bug (v 2.4)

Tags: python, tensorflow

- OS Platform and Distribution: macOS Big Sur and Ubuntu 18 (Google
  colab)
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): pip
- TensorFlow version (use command below): 2.4
- Python version: 3.8.7 on macOS and 3.6 on google colab

I created a few functions to benchmark `tf.TensorArray.write()` operations with python list `append()` and the former takes ages in comparison when writing 1000+ numbers. Here's a colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CySveLoSpbXB5uNWVcCB7ITlTN9dlYDA?usp=sharing) and the results are shown below. My question is, is this normal behavior? I was expecting better performance when used with `tf.function` but it's either not a proper use case or an issue.

```
from time import perf_counter
import tensorflow as tf


def list_appends(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(i)
    return l

def list_to_tensor(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(i)
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(l)


def t_array(n):
    t = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    for i in range(n):
        t = t.write(i, i)
    return t.stack()
    


@tf.function
def t_array_tff(n):
    t = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    for i in range(n):
        t = t.write(i, i)
    return t.stack()


@tf.function
def t_array_tff_tfr(n):
    t = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    for i in tf.range(n):
        t = t.write(i, i)
    return t.stack()
```

**Tests:**

```
n = 100000

%timeit list_appends(n)
```

100 loops, best of 3: 9.09 ms per loop

```
%timeit list_to_tensor(n)  # Same function + converts the resulting list to tf.Tensor
```

The slowest run took 4.30 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10 loops, best of 3: 36 ms per loop

```
%timeit t_array(n)  #  TensorArray
```

1 loop, best of 3: 3.25 s per loop

```
%timeit t_array_tff_tfr(n)  # TensorArray + tf.function + tf.range()
```

1 loop, best of 3: 1.53 s per loop

The following hits a deadlock until I kill the code, throws a lot of errors and I'm not sure whether this is a normal behavior.

```
%timeit t_array_tff(n)  # TensorArray + tf.function + range()
```

Error:

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-8-2ea8237511a6>", line 1, in <module>
    get_ipython().magic('timeit t_array_tff(n)  # TensorArray + tf.function + range()')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2160, in magic
    return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2081, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-59>", line 2, in timeit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py", line 188, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py", line 1057, in timeit
    time_number = timer.timeit(number)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py", line 139, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<magic-timeit>", line 1, in inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 726, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3206, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    user_requested=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 459, in converted_call
    result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmp1hatjldp.py", line 24, in tf__t_array_tff
    ag__.for_stmt(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(range), (ag__.ld(n),), None, fscope), None, loop_body, get_state, set_state, ('t',), {'iterate_names': 'i'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 444, in for_stmt
    _py_for_stmt(iter_, extra_test, body, None, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 473, in _py_for_stmt
    body(target)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 459, in protected_body
    original_body(protected_iter)
  File "/tmp/tmp1hatjldp.py", line 22, in loop_body
    t = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(t).write, (ag__.ld(i), ag__.ld(i)), None, fscope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 350, in converted_call
    return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 479, in _call_unconverted
    return f(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 247, in wrapped
    return _add_should_use_warning(fn(*args, **kwargs),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 1159, in write
    return self._implementation.write(index, value, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 543, in write
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/list_ops.py", line 202, in tensor_list_set_item
    index >= input_list_size,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 4937, in less_equal
    "LessEqual", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 522, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py", line 163, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1540, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 52, in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 265, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 287, in _constant_impl
    "Const", [], [dtype_value.type], attrs=attrs, name=name).outputs[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 592, in _create_op_internal
    compute_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3536, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2027, in __init__
    output_type = pywrap_tf_session.TF_OperationOutputType(tf_output)
KeyboardInterrupt

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1823, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'KeyboardInterrupt' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1132, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 358, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1452, in getframeinfo
    lines, lnum = findsource(frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 170, in findsource
    file = getsourcefile(object) or getfile(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 732, in getmodule
    for modname, module in list(sys.modules.items()):
KeyboardInterrupt
---------------------
```